# The Veins output file is interrupted

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using sumo-1.2.0, and veins-5,and omnetpp-5.5.1.

The Veins output file is interrupted.Is there a solution for this?

Please help me. Thanks.

erlangen.sumo.cfg

```html
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/sumoConfiguration.xsd">
    <input>
        <net-file value="demo.net.xml"/>
        <route-files value="erlangen.rou.xml"/>
    </input>

    <time>
        <begin value="0"/>
        <end value="400"/>
        <step-length value="1"/>
    </time>

    <report>
        <xml-validation value="never"/>
        <xml-validation.net value="never"/>
        <no-step-log value="true"/>
    </report>

    <gui_only>
        <start value="true"/>
    </gui_only>

    <output>
        <lanechange-output value="lanechange.out.xml"/>
        <amitran-output value="amitran.out.xml"/>
    </output>
<remote-port value="54010"/><seed value="0"/><random value="false"/></configuration>
```

amitran.out.xml

```html
    <motionState vehicle="47" speed="2245" time="274000" acceleration="0"/>
    <motionState vehicle="48" speed="2222" time="274000" acceleration="0"/>
    <motionState vehicle="46" speed="2222" time="275000" acceleration="0"/>
    <motionState vehicle="47" speed="2245" time="275000" acceleration="0"/>
    <motionState vehicle="48" speed="2222" time="275000" acceleration="0"/>
    <motionState vehicle="46" speed="2222" time="276000" acceleration="0"/>
    <motionState vehicle="47" speed="2245" time="276000" acceleration=
```

lanechange.out.xml

```html
    <change id="general-car21" type="general-car120" time="172.00" from="central-road_2" to="central-road_1" dir="-1" speed="26.56" pos="2860.37" reason="keepRight" leaderGap="None" leaderSecureGap="None" followerGap="28.05" followerSecureGap="0.81" origLeaderGap="None" origLeaderSecureGap="None"/>
    <change id="general-car15" type="general-car80" time="179.00" from="central-road_1" to="central-road_0" dir="-1" speed="22.22" pos="2982.87" reason="keepRight" leaderGap="61.67" leaderSecureGap="22.22" followerGap="19.22" followerSecureGap="0.00" origLeaderGap="58.42" origLeaderSecureGap="0.81"/>
    <change id="general-car39" type="general-car120" time="179.00" from="central-road_1" to="central-road_0" dir="-1" speed="25.22" pos="1569.01" reason="keepRight" leaderGap="142.20" leaderSecureGap="39.96" followerGap="47.80" followerSecureGap="7.49" origLeaderGap="275.53" origLeaderSecureGap="39.96"/>
    <change id="general-car35" type="general-car100" time="186.00" from="central-road_1" to="central-road_2" dir="1" speed="22.67" pos="2241.03" reason="speedGain" leaderGap="2.64" leaderSecureGap="0.00" followerGap="480.93" followerSecureGap="54.07" origLeaderGap="25.74" origLeaderSecureGap="24.66"/>
    <change id="general-car41" type="general-car100" time="189.00" from="central-road_2" to="central-road_1" dir="-1" speed="27.78" pos="1838.43" reason="keepRight" leaderGap="228.33" leaderSecureGap="56.06" followerGap="112.14" followerSecureGap="24.04" origLeaderGap="441.95" origLeaderSecureGap="77.02"/>
    <change id="general-car36" type="general-car120" time="199.00" from="central-road_2" to="central-road_1" dir="-1" speed="31.51" pos="2647.73" reason="keepRight" leaderGap="296.82" leaderSecureGap="53.92" followerGap="82.08" followerSecureGap="0.00" origLeaderGap="None" origLeaderSecureGap="None"/>
    <change id="general-car31" type="general-car100" time="203.00" from="3to2_1" to="3to2_0" dir="-1" speed="27.78" pos="37.46" reason="keepRight" leaderGap="None" leaderSecureGap="None" followerGap="6.12" followerSecureGap="0.00" origLeaderGap="None" origLeaderSecureGap="None"/>
    <change id="general-car35" type="general-car100" time="211.00" from="central-road_2" t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run SUMO without GUI. If you launch SUMO using `sumo-launchd.py` use:

```
./sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo
```

instead of:

```
./sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo-gui
```

Just tested the erlangen example with the same versions as you are using.
You might also be interested in this answer: [Veins: Get Tripinfo and emissions in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258886/veins-get-tripinfo-and-emissions-in-output)